# forwarding when label value changes (onchange)

Tags: javascript, onchange

I want to redirect when the label text changes.
textbox works but does not work on the label. 
I am using qr code reading project. When the code is read, it writes the value of the labels and it is redirected to that value.

```
<label id="lbltipAddedComment">test</label>        
<label  id="Label1" onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Date=' + this.value;"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is only supported by several `<input>, <select> and <textarea>`

To solve your Problem you could hook into the function that changes the labelText.